# How to rotate existing pdf before uploading

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, cakephp-2.0, uploading

I'm trying to figure out how to rotate pdf files -90 degree when uploading to server. 
*I know I can't ask for a tool or a website etc.* 
But after searching a lot, here on stackoverflow, google, php.net I just couldn't find what I needed. I just hope someone can send me to the right direction.

I'm currently working with cakephp 2.0x. And using the upload plugin from [jose gonzalez upload cakephp](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload)

I tried to write an other function after create and before the save:

```
$this->Post->create();
$this->rotate_pdf($this->request->data['model']['file']);                <-----
if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
```

This is the function

```
plublic function rotate_pdf($pdf){
    pdf_open_file($pdf);
    pdf_rotate($pdf, -90);
    pdf_close($pdf);
    return $pdf;
}
```

But it gives me an error: `undefined function pdf_open_file();`

Here are some working examples: 
http://www.rotatepdf.net/ 
https://www.pdfrotate.com/ 
http://www.rotatepdf.eu/index.html 
But I don't want my script to download the new file, only to upload it to my server.

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

We offer a component (SetaPDF-Core - not free!) that is able to do this in a simple way:

```
<?php
//require autoloader
require_once("library/SetaPDF/Autoload.php");

// create a file writer
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_File("rotated.pdf");
// load document by filename
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename('your.pdf', $writer);

// get pages object
$pages = $document->getCatalog()->getPages();
// get page count
$pageCount = $pages->count();

for ($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber <= $pageCount; $pageNumber++) {
    // get page object for this page
    $page = $pages->getPage($pageNumber);

    // rotate by...
    $page->rotateBy(-90);
}

// save and finish the document
$document->save()->finish();
```

An interactive demo of a simliar script is available [here](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-core/demos/rotate-pdf-page-with-php/).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but i search for a free solution, not a complete product.

Comment: If you could live with a re-creation of the uploaded document you can import it page by page with [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) and rotate the pages by the help of the [Rotations](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script2.php) script or [this](http://www.fpdf.org/phorum/read.php?f=1&i=64819&t=43071) way.